# Page related Automation in Geb

Tags: eclipse, groovy, automation, geb

I have defined 2 "pages" for automation testing. Now, for one particular test, I have defined a setup block in every test with an "at" specifying which page, I am at - which gives me access to the appropriate methods and constants defined for that particular page. Now, I am wondering if I wanted to switch between 2 different pages, how would I go about doing that?

If I have written a script and I am currently "at" page A and I do a series of actions and checks and my test clicks an element that takes me to another page (B), how do I access the page definition from within the same script?

Answer (score 1):

If you click on an element that takes you to a new page, you can just call an "at" on the new page:

`at PageB`

You can also put a "to" in the link's locator that will make this more transparent in your script like so:

```
static content {
  linkToPageB(to:PageB) {"a#pageb"}
}
```

Thus, when you click the linkToPageB, it automatically calls a "to" to the page, which automatically calls an "at" on the page.